# How can I play a flash video on my profile page just like you tube does?

Tags: facebook

I need an application that plays a video as the user clicks on my fan page image ..Youtube is a sample app.
I need exactly the same thing for my app.

As I click share on my fan page, it shares the fan page , I am using the http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php with params title, summary,p[url],images[0],url..

As I click on the image on the user's profile page, It needs to start loading a video.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use facebook's opengraph protocol, you can use og:video tags with swf from opengraph dynamically on your page:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

anytime the page with og:video tags is liked - the swf is automatically embedded on the user's wall, users have to click it to start playing exactly like youtube videos.

Comment: I've tried but am facing problems.A link to my problem is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7471626/how-do-i-use-the-facebook-sharer-meta-tags

Comment: Have a look at this ..jsfiddle.net/ZShEM..Still it does not work as expected

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, Facebook does not allow you to auto play in-line videos.